# How to call a controller function inside AngularJS directive

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-directive

**Controller in page :**

```
(function () {
 'use strict';
  angular.module('LVS').controller('LVSCtrl', LVSCtrl);
  function LVSCtrl($scope) {
   $scope.OnChange = function() {
   // do
   }
  }
 })();
```

This is my directive code
**My Directive code :**

```
(function () {
  'use strict';

  angular.module('LVS')
      .directive('taEmp', taEmp);

  function taEmp() {
      return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            ngModel: '=',
            ngDisabled: '=',
            ngReadonly: '=',
            ngChange: '&',
        },
        templateUrl: 'app/pages/ESS-TA/Common/Directives/TAEmpPicker.html',

    }

    })();
```

**My Directive in page :**

```
<ta-emp ng-model="empCode" ng-change="OnChange()"></ta-emp>
```

My directive not call function in controller

Comment: Please add your `ta-emp` directive.

Comment: `My directive not call function in controller` ... just a guess, but this might be because you don't have any code for your directive.

Comment: i already create this directive

Comment: Why and when do you think OnChange() should be called?

Comment: When empCode is changed

Comment: OK. That answers the "when" question. Now "why" do you think it should be called. Is there anything in the code of your directive calling $scope.ngChange() when empCode is changed? That won't happen by magic.

Comment: Thanks for adding your example directive Athit, I created a solution for you based on your requirements. Please check my answer and suggest.

Comment: thanks, lin and all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made it work by using `$watch` inside your directive and parsing an controller function as param into it. The function gonna be executed once the input value has changed.

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.name = '';
    $scope.someFunction = function (data) {
       console.log(data);
    };
});

myApp.directive('myDirective', function () {

  return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
        model: '=ngModel',
        function: '='
      },
      template: '<input type="text" ng-model="model" function="function" my-directive>',
      link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
         scope.$watch('model', function (newValue, oldValue) {
           if (newValue && newValue !== oldValue) {
             if (typeof scope.function === 'function') {
               scope.function('test');
             }
           }
         }, true);
      }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <my-directive ng-model="name" function="someFunction"></my-directive>
</div>
```

Comment: @AthitUpakan glad to help ya!

Comment: why  scope.function(); in directive can call function with parameter too?
ex. $scope.OnChange = function(data) { //.... });

Comment: @AthitUpakan yep this is possible.

Comment: I'm newbie, do you have document or link for this solution? thanks again.

Comment: Be aware that using `ng-model` for an attribute name will instantiate the [ngModelController](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController) and attach it to the element. Since the directive does not properly use the ng`modelController` API, the `ng-change` directive will not work. Use of the `ng-` prefix is reserved for AngularJS core directives. Please avoid using it in custom directives.

Comment: @georgeawg thanks for the hint. Have you a bad example for me where the problem is been shown?

Comment: See [AngularJS Wiki - Best Practices](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Best-Practices).